# angular js Service/Factory attributes behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have a question about AngularJS behavior (JS behavior in general)

I have an Angular factory injected into a controller.

Here's  a snippet of the controller code

```
$scope.localObjCollection= myObjFactorySvc.getObjCollection();
```

Let's assume that myObjFactorySvc.getObjCollection() returns the following object

```
[{"id":1"name":null,"address":null,"email":null},
{"id":2"name":null,"address":null,"email":null},
{"id":3"name":null,"address":null,"email":null},
{"id":4"name":null,"address":null,"email":null},
]
```

So, I'm pretty much using the factory to get the collection and storing it in   `$scope.localObjCollection`. 
My question is does `$scope.localObjCollection` have the value (copy) of the data returned by `getObjCollection()` or just a reference.

So if somewhere down in the controller source code, if I do 
`$scope.localObjCollection.push(newObj)`, does it also update the original collection in the Factory? It should I guess but I would like to understand the correct behavior

Comment: AFAIK, if it is an object, it should be a reference, but if it is a value, it is a copy. So, it should update the original collection. You can use `angular.copy` to make a clone of the collection.

Comment: Here is a small demo showing you the differences: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUA3zFcMCHj5SNDDZlwT?p=preview

Comment: Since factories are singletons, you can share your data easily across your application.

Comment: If you would like to share copies of the data, you could use `angular.copy` inside the `getObjCollection` when returning the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array in JavaScript is an object and objects in JS are always passed/assigned by reference. Therefore your code would also update the original collection in the Factory, assuming that your *myObjFactorySvc.getObjCollection()* is something like this:

```
myObjFactorySvc.getObjCollection = function() { return someArrayVariable; }
```